# Which is true $A$ is subset of $B$ or $B$ is subset of $A$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Consider the sets dened by the real solutions of the inequalities $$A=\{(x,y):x^2+y^4\le 1\}$$ and $$B=\{(x,y):x^4+y^6\le 1\}$$Then which is true $A$ is subset of $B$ or $B$ is subset of $A$.

This is [Question No. $10.$](http://www.isical.ac.in/~deanweb/sylques.pdf) of this paper. Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try graphic method...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

$$(x,y)\in A\implies x^2+y^4\le 1\implies |x|,|y|\le 1$$

so

$$ x^4+y^6\le x^2+y^4\implies \ldots\ldots$$

Comment: "$(x,y) \in \implies$ […]" - excuse me? I think you accidentally a character.

Comment: Yes @kahen, thanks. I already corrected the post. BTW, you also forgot a word ("forgot", perhaps?)...:)

Comment: No, [I intentionally left it out](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/i-accidentally).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try the following points: $$(0.5,0.5),~~(0.8,0.8),~~\{(0.7,0.9),(0.7,0.8)\}$$ I know this is an strange way based on trial and error method. I did it just because your question is a multiple choices.

Answer (score 0):

The set A looks more like circle, the B looks more like a squre... and the almost-circle lies inside of almost-square. try that on your own...

A may be expressed as $y\in (-(1-x^2)^\frac{1}{4},(1-x^2)^\frac{1}{4})$

B may be expressed as $y\in (-(1-x^4)^\frac{1}{6},(1-x^4)^\frac{1}{6})$

You have to prove that $(1-x^2)^\frac{1}{4} \leq (1-x^4)^\frac{1}{6}$ so that the almost-circle doesn't reach out of the almost-squre.